# How to efficiently wait for data becoming available in RDBS (PostgreSQL) table?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I'm building a web service which reserves unique items to users.

Service is required to handle high amounts of concurrent requests that should avoid blocking each other as much as possible. Each incoming request must reserve n-amount of unique items of the desired type, and then process them successfully or release them back to the reservables list so they can be reserved by an another request. A succesful processing contains multiple steps like communicating with integrated services and other time consuming steps, so keeping items reserved with a DB transaction until the end would not be an efficient solution.

Currently I've implemented a solution where reservable items are stored in a buffer DB table where items are being locked and deleted by incoming requests with SELECT FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED. As service must support multiple item types, this buffer table contains only n amount of items per type at a time as the table size would otherwise grow into too big as there is about ten thousand different types. When certain item types are all reserved (selected and removed) the request locks the item type and adds more reservable items into the buffer. This fill operation requires integration calls and may take some time. During the fill, all other operations needs to wait until the filling operation finishes and items become available. This is where the problem arises. When thousands of requests wait for the same item type to become available in the buffer, each needs to poll this information somehow.

What could be an efficient solution for this kind of polling?

Comment: I would say that "copying" types to a temporary table is not something that would contribute at all, since you still need to SELECT from the source table and INSERT into the temporary table. Moreover, (and this I state with some reservations since I'm not very well acquainted with PostgreSQL), having request queuing is NOT going to resolve anything but rather the opposite, meaning, once the first request enters a queue (because a previous request locked records), the chances for the next request to get queued too would increase. I would suggest to try and speed-up the process as a first step.

Comment: Thanks for your response @FDavidov. The way how requests get queued is actually the problem. Current implementation uses simple query loop, where requests release their transaction and sleep a bit before they retry to reserve items from the buffer. However, this approach will consume unnecessary resources by constanly reserving and freeing connections from the pool. I would not be suprised if this kind of consumer-producer problem would have a already resolved with databases as well.

Comment: Allow me to rephrase what your wrote: "_The way how requests get queued is actually the problem_" should be "_The fact that request get enqueued **is** the problem_".

Comment: "all other operations needs to wait until the filling operation finishes"  Here you say it should wait, but earlier you say they should not block.  Blocking and waiting are the same thing, aren't they?  Can you clarify what you want?  Should they not block, except in this one instance?

Comment: "As service must support multiple item types, this buffer table contains only n amount of items per type at a time as the table size would otherwise grow into too big as there is about ten thousand different types."  Is this "too big" a theoretical concern, or have you actually experienced the problem?  What was the nature of the problem experienced?  Did it slow things down, or just take up more disk space than desired?

Comment: Hi @jjanes and thanks for the comments. Operations may block/wait only during the buffer fill as only one instance per type is allowed to perform it at a time. This is because it performs some operations that needs to be accessed in a mutually exclusive way (e.g. item creation stuff which also requires interaction with the integrations). "Too big" is actually a theoretical and practical concern as there may be millions of items per type. With one buffer table that could easily lead into a scenario where table could have over 10 000 000 000 items.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Refect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "real" answer is to start the refill process when the stock gets low, rather than when it is completely depleted.  Then it would already be refilled by the time anyone needs to block on it.  Or perhaps you could make the refill process work asynchronously, so that the new rows are generated near-instantly and then the integrations are called later.  So you would enqueue the integrations, rather than the consumers.

But barring that, it seems like you want the waiters to lock the "item type" in a mode incompatible with the how the refiller locks it.  Then it will naturally block, and be released once the refiller is done.  The problem is that if you want to assemble an order of 50 things and the 47th is depleted, do you want to maintain the reservation on the previous 46 things while you wait?

Presumably your reservation is not blocking anyone else, unless the one you have reserved is the last one available.  In which case you are not really blocking them, just forcing them to go through the refill process, which would have had to be done eventually anyway.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @jjanes. Refill can only be started when all existing items have been consumed. This is related to the way how the process flow works and how integrations handle these item batches used to refill the buffer. So proactive or  asynchronous refill processing is unfortunately not an option. The first item reservation which cannot be fullfilled should reserve all remaining items and go and perform the buffer refill to get more items to fullfill the request.